# How to make a 'log in with Spotify' authentication system using Firebase?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, firebase, spotify, social-authentication

I have a web page which I want to make it only available to users after they log-in using their Spotify account. I am using Firebase for backend.

I haven't implemented any social authentication before, so an in-depth answer will be much appreciated.

Comment: Any solution until now?

Comment: not yet unfortunately

Comment: They released a new Firebase for the google IO. It may contain some extra features for auth. Did not checked yet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a great exemple to implement Firebase auth with Instagram Oauth. It will be exactly the same for Spotify.
Read it here : [Authenticate your Firebase users with Instagram](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/10/authenticate-your-firebase-users-with.html)

**edit**: And now there is also a sample for auth with [Spotify + Firebase functions](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/Node-1st-gen/spotify-auth)